# RecyclerView memory issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

just change from ListView to RecyclerView. But, face memory issue.

https://github.com/yau34992004/ReuseYourLayoutStructure

Try to download this source. Start app and check demo one for Grid View. Open memory monitor and scroll up and down several times. Will see memory grow gradually.

Anyone know why?

Edit:

Recycler Adapter

```
public class DemoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> mArrayList;

public DemoAdapter() {
    mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public DemoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.viewholder_demo, viewGroup, false);
    DemoViewHolder demoViewHolder = new DemoViewHolder(view);
    return demoViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DemoViewHolder demoViewHolder, int i) {
    demoViewHolder.setTitle(i + "");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public void setArrayList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

    if (arrayList == null || arrayList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("youShouldNotSetEmptyArrayList");
    }

    mArrayList.addAll(arrayList);
}
}
```

viewholder_demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--<Space-->
    <!--android:layout_width="50dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="50dp" />-->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
```

Fragment

```
public abstract class RecyclerFragment<T extends RecyclerView.Adapter<?>> extends Fragment {

protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
protected T mAdapter;
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = mRecyclerModel.provideAdapter();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResourcesId(), container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return view;
}

protected int getLayoutResourcesId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_vertical_recycler;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
    mRecyclerView = null;
}


public T getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}
```

Comment: please point to specific parts of your code and do not just post your entire project and tell us to download it and run it

Comment: My bad. Just add some codes

Comment: i also try this one , very interesting
it will oom while just scrolling up and down